# error when trying to assign local address value

Tags: go, networking, ipv6

I'm trying to set the local address of an http request like so:

```
localAddr, err := net.ResolveIPAddr("ip6", laddr)

if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

localTCPAddr := net.TCPAddr{
    IP: localAddr.IP,
}

client := &http.Client{
    Transport: &http.Transport{
        Proxy: http.ProxyFromEnvironment,
        DialContext: (&net.Dialer{
            LocalAddr: &localTCPAddr,
            Timeout:   30 * time.Second,
            KeepAlive: 30 * time.Second,
            DualStack: true,
        }).DialContext,
        MaxIdleConns:          100,
        IdleConnTimeout:       90 * time.Second,
        TLSHandshakeTimeout:   10 * time.Second,
        ExpectContinueTimeout: 1 * time.Second,
    },
}
```

For reference: the laddr variable would look like this:

```
 2620:13a:c020:0016:1f7b:169c:846f:218a:49152
```

The error occurs when trying to send the request, and this is the error: 
2018/11/25 00:17:58 lookup 2620:13a:c020:0016:1f7b:169c:846f:218a:49152: no such host.

I'm not sure whats causing this error. Some details about my environment: its a Ubuntu fresh VPS, with almost nothing installed.

EDIT: 
Even when removing the port as pointed out below I still get this error:
 dial tcp [2620:13a:c020:16:1f7b:169c:846f:218a]:0         ->[remoteip]:[remoteport] bind: cannot assign requested address

Comment: 2620:13a:c020:0016:1f7b:169c:846f:218a:49152  is not a valid IPV6. As an example,  2001:4860:4860::8888 is a valid IPV6

Comment: 49152 is the port, not explicitly part of the address @Ehsan.Saradar

Comment: Then it is not written correctly. To avoid confusion, the IPv6 address should be in brackets, i.e. `[2620:13a:c020:0016:1f7b:169c:846f:218a]:49152`. Your program needs to do what all other programs do, and parse out the address before trying to use it in a `DialContext`. [`net.SplitHostPort()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#SplitHostPort) will do this for you.

Answer (score 3):

This `2620:13a:c020:0016:1f7b:169c:846f:218a:49152` is not a valid IPv6 address. You have an extra `49152` which is not even a valid IPv6 hextet. This `2620:13a:c020:0016:1f7b:169c:846f:218a` is a valid IPv6 address.

[Validator](https://ip-lookup.net/information.php?ip=2620:13a:c020:0016:1f7b:169c:846f:218a)

**Edit**

Address resolution is not the same as making a connection. If you want to make a connection rather than resolving the address, that is the time that you need the port.

e.g.

```
net.Dial("tcp", "[2620:13a:c020:16:1f7b:169c:846f:218a]:49152")
```

Comment: As mentioned by @robert in the comments, is `49152` the port? If so, remove that as the port is not needed when resolving an IP address.

Comment: Yes is the port. However when removing I run into this problem: 
 dial tcp [2620:13a:c020:16:1f7b:169c:846f:218a]:0 (my IP, from port 0?)        ->[different ip, remote i think]  bind: cannot assign requested address

Comment: Put, you port after the brackets `net.Dial("tcp", "[2620:13a:c020:16:1f7b:169c:846f:218a]:49152")`

Comment: Well where should I add it in the code above?  There's no "room" to add it between resolving the IP and setting it in the dial func. Also, I'm not sure if I'm intercommunicating but I don't necessarily want to set the port, I would rather do it automatically. However if I don't set a port it will default to :0 and throw a different error there.

Comment: Revision: I see what you mean. However, I want to set the local Address field for the client, and let net/http handle actual connection and the port. For some reason though, the port is 0 and then will panic with this: bind: cannot assign requested address

Comment: If you want to bind a port, then set it in `net.TCPAddr{
    IP: localAddr.IP, Port: 49152,
}`

Comment: This is what I'm looking for, however this still leads to the " bind: cannot assign requested address". Any theories? I should be routed the subnet which contains this, but maybe I need to configure ubuntu?

Comment: @robert, port zero tells the OS to pick any available port. If you don't care about the local port this is exactly what you want. See https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Listen

Comment: I think you have an issue with your network settings. I can bind to my ipv6 address on my vps with this same code. Is your ipv6 scope global?

Comment: @Peter Thanks for letting me know, will do. @/ssemilla I'm sure this is the problem. I remember reading something about an "ip6" command to run on linux so I could bind the ipv6 address but can remember the full command or if thats even correct. What do you mean by scope. This is on a fresh server that was just routed a subnet containing this IP. I have not done anything on the server itself though.

Comment: In my case I just added the ipv6 address that was set by my vps provider. Something like `sudo ifconfig eth0 inet6 add <ipv6 address>`. And this setup a global scoped ipv6 address in my network.

Comment: Hmm, well two things:
In my case I don't have the network interface eth0, but trying to add the IP to "lo" will still result in cannot bind.
Also, can I add the full subnet in cidr notatation like this:  sudo ifconfig lo inet6 add 2620:13a:c020::/56

Comment: You should definitely not use loopback. There should be a network interface that has connectivity outside your vps.

Answer (score 0):

Error was on my end: I didn't assign the address to an interface before. Thanks for informing me about ports and all that, much appreciated.